# Why does ffmpeg quit before adding all requested frames to a clip?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation, frame

I have a problem with using ffmpeg to collect .jpg files from security cameras and making .avis from them.
The cameras FTP in frames on a regular basis as fast as they can, accumulating some 16000 to 20000 over the course of a day.  During the night, when my Hughesnet data cap is relaxed, I've used a cron job to concatenate these frames into an avi that can be saved/scanned in the morning.

A typical file name might be:
`FrontDeer_20230218-101637.jpg` where
`FrontDeer` is the camera name,
`20230218` is the date and
`101637` is the time.

```bash
ls -l Front\*18-\*.jpg | wc -l gives a count of 16284 files.
```

My failed attempts at creating a video were variations on:

```bash
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i 'Front\*18-\*.jpg' -s 800x600 -v verbose Ftest2.avi
```

which consistently stops at 2354 frames encoded.

the verbose output from ffmpeg ends with the following:

```
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame= 2534 fps= 24 q=8.8 Lsize=    8122kB time=00:05:16.75 bitrate= 210.1kbits/s
video:8056kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.821897%
Input file #0 (Front\*18-\*.jpg):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 2534 packets read (128534848 bytes); 2534 frames decoded;
  Total: 2534 packets (128534848 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (Ftest2.avi):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 2534 frames encoded; 2534 packets muxed (8249089 bytes);
  Total: 2534 packets (8249089 bytes) muxed
2534 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
```

I can't say I've read all the ffmpeg docs, or understood all I've read.  In any event I haven't found a solution to what appears to be something straightforward yet doesn't work.
Is there some sort of buffer limit I have to set to allow more frames to be encoded?

The system specifics are

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 28
Model name:            Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N455   @ 1.66GHz

               Total       used         free         shared     buff/cache available
Mem:           1982         421          94          58        1466        1284
Swap:          2035         108        1927

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
```

Great thanks for any help

Comment: ffmpeg will abort if it encounters an image file of size 0 bytes. Check for that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll have to wait for the problem to come up again to confirm.  I concluded the camera(s) to be at fault because subsequent days of snaps have not repeated the problem. I can't check for the 0 byte file probability because pretty much all the images get purged daily.  The whole idea of making clips from them is to avoid saving ~20000 files per camera daily.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have bothered the community.
It turns out that the problem wasn't with ffmpeg but that the cameras would occasionally send a corrupted frame to an appropriately named file.  It was at that point that ffmpeg failed, but was not at fault.
Thanks for any attention paid. I hope this question/answer doesn't get pulled up very often in regards to ffmpeg as it doesn't really apply.